# How to specify a group of years in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Basic SQL question about specifying a group of years in a table.  Working on a database and it is wanting me to list the author, title, publication date and retail price.  I have that part down but its also ask to output all titles that start with "D" and were published in the 1970s.

I have the first part down: (this is how we are taught btw)

```
SELECT `fAuthorID`,`fTitle`,`fPubYear`,`fRetailPrice`
FROM `tBooks`
WHERE
```

But I cant seem to be able to get it to output the authors with a "D" and years 1970-1979 to display.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  relational

Comment: Of course, otherwise you wouldn't be using SQL. But are you using Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: oh my bad, in class it is oracle i believe

Comment: The syntax you have shown (those dreaded backticks) would be invalid for Oracle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT fauthorID, fTitle, fPubYear, fReatailPrice
FROM tbooks
WHERE fTitle Like 'D%' AND fPubYear Like '197_'
```

Comment: @Dewie Using `LIKE` on a number is bad coding style and will not always work the way you expect it because of the evil implicit data type conversion that is going on there. Other databases would simply reject that. `LIKE` is for numbers, not for strings. Use `where fpubyear between 1970 and 1979` instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `fpubyear`  is a number (integer) column, the correct way of querying for a continuous range of years is to use the `BETWEEN` operator.

```
SELECT fauthorID, fTitle, fPubYear, fReatailPrice
FROM tbooks
WHERE fTitle Like 'D%' 
  AND fPubYear BETWEEN 1970 and 1979;
```

The between operator *includes* both ends. It has the added benefit that an index on `fpubyear` can be used to quickly find the matching rows - which is not the case if the number first needs to be converted to a string to be able to apply the `LIKE` operator on it.

---

`LIKE` is for character values ("strings"), it should not be used with other types - especially not when relying on the evil implicit data type conversion. Other database would simply reject applying like on a number column.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Dewie 
 You an use this query,

```
SELECT fAuthorID,fTitle,fPubYear,fRetailPrice
FROM tBooks
WHERE fTitle like 'D%' and fPubYear like '%197%';
```

Hope this will give you result. Any issues just let me know

Comment: Using `LIKE` on a number is bad coding style and will not always work the way you expect it because of the evil implicit data type conversion that is going on there. Other databases would simply reject that. `LIKE` is for numbers, not for strings. Use `where fpubyear between 1970 and 1979` instead

Comment: If you assume `fpubyear` is a `DATE` column, using `LIKE` is even worse.

Comment: Just let me know how the data is populated in **fPubYear** column. What data type actually it is.